# istream overloading -reading string from file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I am trying to read a list of Person objects from a file, outputs those objects to an in-memory stream. I am able to get it working if I dont have to read from a file, I can manaully enter each object value and its working fine, but I am struggling to pipe the extracted line from file as input to istream >> overloading operator

Reads from a file

```
string str
while (getline(inFile, str))
   {
     cout << "line" << str << endl; // I am getting each line
     cin >> people // if I manually enter each parameter of object it works fine
     str >> people // ?? - doesnt work - how do i pipe??
   }

Person.cpp
// operator overloading for in operator
istream& operator>> (istream &in, People &y)
{

    in >> y.firstName;
    in >> y.lastName;
    in >> y.ageYears;
    in >> y.heightInches;
    in >> y.weightPounds;
    return in;
}

class People
{
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  int ageYears;
  double heightInches;
  double weightPounds;

   // stream operator
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, People&);
  friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, People&);
};
```

Comment: [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: Sorry not able to get ur question - I am not writing to file ..I am able to read a line from a file and trying to pipe it as input for an object ..

Comment: @Zeta : can you please elaborate how can i use istringstream to resolve the issue

Comment: `std::istringstream ss(str); ss >> people;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a string `std::string str`. You want to use formatted extractions on that string. However, `std::string` isn't a `std::istream`. After all, it's just a simple string.

Instead, you need an `istream` with the same contents as the string. This can be done with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream in(str);

in >> people;
```

Comment: @oneday: I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answers yet. See [this post on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how it works.